# Read data sent to php file

Tags: php

Im working with so called webhooks. What basically happens is. There's a process happening in the background and when that process finishes it will send a POST request to an URL that I have to specify. For example 'www.bla/process.php'.

The post request that is sent will have a body of data. My question is , is it possible to read the data that is sent and just print it out for example?

Comment: So `echo json_encode($_POST)`? Or `echo file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: _“is it possible to read the data that is sent”_ - well if it wasn’t, then sending it in the first place would probably be utterly pointless to begin with. _“and just print it out for example”_ - yes, but there will be no one around able to _look_ at it (because this happens on your server) - so if you need this info for debugging purposes, then you better write it to a file (that you can afterwards download from your server to inspect its contents.)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

It is possible to pass info from one page to another and print it out for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many method's...

```
// THE SAME
echo $_POST['DATA1'];
echo ($_POST['DATA1']);
// THE SAME

// IF = DATA IS SET AND NOT EMPTY
if (isset($_POST['DATA1']) && !empty($_POST['DATA1'])) {
    $DATA1 = $_POST['DATA1'];
}
echo($DATA1);
```